# Reading log files in Java

Tags: java, logging, file-io

I am trying to read a log file in Java that only displays one line per page view. If I read my file using the method below, will it still read through the entire log file or will it stop after the first page because there is no other line to read on that page?

```
    try{
           FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
           String strLine;
           //Reading line by line
           while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
             getUsersForPage(strLine);
           }
           br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: The only thing that can stop the `while` loop is when `getUsersForPage` throws an exception, so if it doesn't, then it will read the whole file.

Comment: As Jesper said the file will most likely be read entirely. What you get in the end depends on what `getUsersForPage(line)` does.

Comment: Thank you. It runs just fine.